# Drawing ER diagrams inferred from functional dependencies

Tags: gratis, software-development

Sometimes I need to draw a quick [ER diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) and I do not want to spend too much time considering the layout, but rather just want to visualize it.

The other extra what I need that on DB theory class we computed, inferred ER model from functional dependencies. It was a quite complicated algorithm. Is it something like that on internet? So the input could be also the list of the dependencies.

It can be a mobile, desktop, or a web-app.

Comment: On the page you reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#ER_diagramming_tools and reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISE_Editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such things I prefer **[Grapviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)**. You can list the dependencies in a simple plain-text file, and then have a choice of different processors to generate output. Best explained using an example:

```
digraph G {

hda -> hda1;
hda -> hda2;
hda -> hda3;
hda -> hda4;
}
```

run with the `dot` processor would generate something like this:

[image: Graphviz example]
<sup>Graphviz example (click image for larger variant)</sup>

*Graphviz* is supported by many tools, there are plugins for a lot of software products, and you also can use it stand-alone. For more details, you can also check the [corresponding Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz).

#### Some further readings:

All the following stuff is using *Graphviz*:

- [Drawing Graphs using Dot and Graphviz](http://www.tonyballantyne.com/graphs.html) (especially see: [6.5. Entity Relationship](http://www.tonyballantyne.com/graphs.html#sec-6-5))
- [Using GraphViz for Database Schema Visualization](http://www.drdobbs.com/using-graphviz-for-database-schema-visua/199102082)
- [Simple Entity Relationship Diagram using GraphViz](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1506/) (django code example)
- [Rails-ERD](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd) is a project using Graphviz to generate ER diagrams
- a [list of Graphviz resources](http://floss.zoomquiet.io/data/20090310211844/index.html)
- [another resource list](http://www.graphviz.org/content/resources)
- [Colorize table name in Graphviz entity-relationship diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22673352/2533433) (on our sister-site)
- [Creating ER diagrams from SQL](https://techmania.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/creating-er-diagrams-from-sql/) (though from 2008, the described project "[SQLFairy](http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/)" is still under active development)
- [Generating Database Schema With SQL and GraphViz](http://pwnguin.net/generating-database-schema-with-sql-and-graphviz.html)

Comment: Do you know is it a way to produce ER model if I have the  functional dependencies as input?

Comment: I've not explicitly worked with complex ER diagrams, so I'm not sure how far it goes. The example I've presented is just a very basic one, there are tons of ways to fine-tune (colors, fillings, labels, fonts, and more). Doing a [Google image search on "graphviz ER"](https://www.google.de/search?q=graphviz+ER&ie=UTF-8&nfpr=1&tbm=isch) gives you a ton of examples to see whether it might fit your needs concerning possible results. [Rails-ERD](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd) is a project using Graphviz for ER diagrams, maybe that might be worth a closer look.

Comment: János, I've updated my answer with some additional resources. As I've already mentioned, plenty of projects are using *Graphviz* the one or other way. I've collected some resources with relation to your question. Some of the examples might even be "separate answers" – but not having used any of them, I could not give any recommendations personally ;)

Answer (score 1):

I generally use [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) for drawing both ER and UML Diagrams. It's got a simple drag and drop interface useful for visualizing ER models on the go. It won't compute functional dependencies for you though.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own simplified ER diagram drawer, you can download from App Store for free: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/draw-er-diagram/id935879437?mt=8